# Creating a simple macro using basic keyboard commands in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macros

I have a sheet with data in 4 unique rows in a single column.

Example:

```
| Column A |
| Cell 1   |
| Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   |
| Cell 4   |
| -blank-  |
```

I would like a macro that will adjust the data to a single row with 4 columns.

Example:

```
| Column A |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   | Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
```

I attempted to manually record a macro using keyboard commands (arrow keys, ctrl+x, ctrl+v).  This resulted in a macro that only executes in the specific cell ranges that I recorded the macro in.  Here is the resulting code:

```
    /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

    function TrashAddressAdjust() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRan());
    spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A3').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
    spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A4').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
    }
    ;
```

I would like the macro to start in whatever cell is active/selected, i.e. Cell 1.  Then move Cell 2, Cell 3, and Cell 4 to their columns next to cell 1.  Lastly, it would delete the blank row and move the active cell to the beginning of the next data set, i.e. the next Cell 1.

I hope this all makes sense and I didn't over-explain everything.  I literally want a macro that will execute these commands wherever the active cell is:

```
    ⬇ ctrl+x, 
    ➡ ⬆ ctrl+v, 
    ⬇ ⬇ ⬅ ctrl+x, 
    ➡ ➡ ⬆ ⬆ ctrl+v,  
    ⬇ ⬇ ⬇ ⬅ ⬅ ctrl+x, 
    ➡ ➡ ➡ ⬆ ⬆ ⬆ ctrl+v, 
    ⬇ ⬅ ⬅ ⬅ delete row.
```

This should leave the active cell in my next Cell 1 dataset.  Now I can just rinse and repeat.

Sorry to be so wordy, thank you in advance for any help.

I tried to manually record the macro but it only executes in the specific cell range that I recorded in.

Comment: It's not really efficient to do it the way you are suggesting.  I'd strongly recommend that you stop writing macros the way that the macro recorder does and learn how to write scripts without using activate or spreadsheet.getActive anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to offset from the active range to the right and to up in a loop:

```
function transpose() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    sh = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    activeRange = sh.getActiveRange(),
    items = 4;
  for (let i = 1; i < items; i++) {
    activeRange.offset(i, 0).moveTo(activeRange.offset(-i, i));
  }
  sh.deleteRow(activeRange.getRow() + items);
  sh.setActiveRange(activeRange.offset(items, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function allows you to select the top row and rows below it that you wish to move to right of it all at one time.  You can select as many rows as you wish.

```
function miniTranpose() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues().flat();
  const [row, col, h, w] = [rg.getRow(), rg.getColumn(), rg.getHeight(), rg.getWidth()];
  if (w == 1) {
    sh.getRange(row, col, h, 1).clearContent()
    sh.getRange(row, col, 1, h).setValues([vs]);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Just select the top row and all the rows you wish to move and run this function.

The chances are good that if you have a lot of these rows in a data set you could have it done on the entire data set with the use of some pivoting function which remove the need for any operator intervention.

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

By the way if you wish to undo this operation.  Just put the focus back on the page and press ctrl-z

Comment: OK, that's cool but I'm not sure it is exactly what I need.  This inline reply sucks.  So, I have 4 rows of data and then 1 blank row.  This repeats down to row 8150.  So, there are a lot of entries.  I just want all the data in 4 columns instead of all in one row.  I tried TheMaster's code above and it works but I can't just speed mash my hotkey and let it run a bunch of times in a row.  If I do this, the first couple times run fine but then it starts to loose the data in Cells 2, 3, and 4.  So, I need to run the macro, make sure it runs correctly, and then run it again.  This takes too long.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  What  specifically would like me to do?

Comment: I'd prefer if you can show me rather than tell me. Because I don't like to read.

Comment: No problem.  How do I record my screen?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-9EfBQBNwuR4EbuRgVCpWQ1HHEGHj_cD/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: I was able to make a link to a screen capture but not sure how to make it show up inline.